# mouseZoomable does not work with elasticX on line chart

Tags: dc.js

I have code of lineChart

as below,

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.index;}),
    profitGrp = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.profit});

var profitChart = dc.lineChart("#profit-chart")
    .width($("#profit-chart").parent().width())
    .height(400)
    .dimension(dim)
    .mouseZoomable(true)
    .x(d3.scale.linear()).xAxisPadding(0.25).elasticX(true)
    .group(profitGrp, "Profit")
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(400).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .margins({left: 100, right: 40, top: 40, bottom: 40})
    .brushOn(false);
```

But I can't mouse zoom in/out.

What should I do? I think it is because of `elasticX(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, zoom is contradictory to `elasticX(true)`

One trick, if you want "elastic once" behavior, is:

```
chart.on('postRender', function(chart) {
    chart.elasticX(false);
});
```

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In my case Gordon answer didn´t work.
So there is another aproach, try to use "preRedraw" event:

```
chart.on('preRedraw', function(chart) {
    chart.elasticX(false);
});
```